# While dividing an angular page vertically in two columns what should be used ng-view, div, table, iframe

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to design a angular page like this:
[image]

In this page on the basis of the slections made in LHS pane, data would be rendered in RHS pane.

I need some help and suggestion, what should be used while designing such type of page. I have gone through some examples on internet and found this could be achieved through div, table, iframe and ng-view.
So, which is the best option for designing this page.
Note: This page contains angular directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you can try using [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) from **angular ui-router**. You can then define your views simply in `div` using `ui-view` tag as:

```
<body>
  <div ui-view="filters"></div>
  <div ui-view="tabledata"></div>
  <div ui-view="graph"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, will try this.